# ¿cómo haces distinct en tabla foránea?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

buen día, estoy tratando de obtener datos de una tabla foránea. hasta ahora, tengo esto en el controlador:

```
 IList<customerModel> customerList = new List<customerModel>();
            var query = from customerModel in context.clientes
                        where !customerModel.rutas.ruta_especial.Value
                        where customerModel.rutas.tipo_ruta!="F"
                        where customerModel.rutas.id_ruta!=54 || customerModel.rutas.id_ruta!=74
                        select customerModel;
            var customers = query.Distinct().ToList();
            foreach (var customerData in customers)
            {
                customerList.Add(new customerModel()

                {

                    Id_Cliente = customerData.id_cliente,
                    Nombres = customerData.Nombres,
                    Id_Ruta = customerData.rutas.id_ruta,
                    Id_Agente = customerData.id_agente.Value,
                    Created_At = customerData.created_at,
                    Nombre_Agente= customerData.agentes.Nombres,
                    Descripcion_Ruta=customerData.rutas.descripcion,
                }) ;;

            }
            return View(customerList);
```

la variable en cuestión que quiero obtener es `Descripcion_Ruta`, como pueden ver, viene de una tabla aparte llamada `rutas`, lo intento recuperar en la vista de esta manera:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
           <label><input type="checkbox" /> 
           <span>@item.Descripcion_Ruta.Distinct()</span></label>
           <br />
     }
```

pero ese `distinct`, se está aplicando al texto que imprime, no a los elementos en sí, como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen:
[image: ejemplo de cómo se ve]

en teoría, con el `distinct()` la consulta debería mostrarme a lo sumo 10 registros, y aparentemente son más de 300. ¿qué debería de hacer para que esto funcione?

Answer (score 1):

No deberias realizar ningun `foreach` si estas utilizando `linq` ya que podrias transforma directamente

```
var query = from cliente in context.clientes
                where !cliente.rutas.ruta_especial.Value
                where cliente.rutas.tipo_ruta!="F"
                where cliente.rutas.id_ruta!=54 || customerModel.rutas.id_ruta!=74
            select new customerModel()
            {

                Id_Cliente = cliente.id_cliente,
                Nombres = cliente.Nombres,
                Id_Ruta = cliente.rutas.id_ruta,
                Id_Agente = cliente.id_agente.Value,
                Created_At = cliente.created_at,
                Nombre_Agente= cliente.agentes.Nombres,
                Descripcion_Ruta= cliente.rutas.descripcion,
            };

List<customerModel> customerList = query.ToList();

return View(customerList);
```

Ademas la propiedad `rutas` parace ser una entidad simple ya que veo usas en la query `rutas.id_ruta` no podrias acceder a la propiedad directamente si fuera un lista que muestre valores repetidos

Comment: rutas es una tabla foránea, estoy utilizando linq to sql

Comment: pero si es una tabla porque esa propiedad no es un `List<>` o collection de algun tipo ? no podrias acceder a una propiedad de esa coleccion como lo estas realizando en el linq si fuera una relacion uno a muchos